# Display the user object array in react app using drizzle

Tags: truffle, dapps, ethereum-wallet-dapp, dapp-development, drizzle

I have been trying to do a simple use case where we return all the user details

please find my code

myComponent.js

```
<div className="section">
        <h2>JurStatus</h2>
        <p>
          <strong>Get Status: </strong>
          <ContractData
            drizzle={drizzle}
            drizzleState={drizzleState}
            contract="JurStatus"
            method="getUser"
          />
        </p>
      </div>
```

contract file

```
function getUser(address _address) public view returns(string memory name, string memory surname, uint age) {
         //if(users[_address].age == 0) throw;
        return (users[_address].name, users[_address].surname, users[_address].age);        
    }
```

In my browser im getting this error
[image]

Why is it showing fetching . What am i doing wrong here .

Thanks

Comment: What exactly is not clear to you in the error-message that you're getting (given in the title of your question)???

Comment: @goodvibration Changed it , I found the error in console , Do you have any idea why its showing fetching in UI .